# How to read then parse with split and write into a text file?

Tags: python, split, io, readline, modulus

I'm struggling to get readline() and split() to  work together as I was expecting. Im trying to use .split(')') to cut down some data from a text file and write some of that data to a next text file.

I have tried writing everything from the line.
I have tried [cnt % 2] to get what I expected.

```
   line = fp.readline()
   fw = open('output.txt', "w+")
   cnt = 1
   while line:
       print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, line.strip()))
       line = fp.readline()
       line = line.split(')')[0]
       fw.write(line + "\n")
       cnt += 1
```

Example from the text file im reading from.

WELD 190 Manufacturing I Introduction to MasterCAM (3)
1½ hours lecture - 4½ hours laboratory
Note: Cross listed as DT 190/ENGR 190/IT 190
This course will introduce the students to MasterCAM and 2D and basic 3D
modeling. Students will receive instructions and drawings of parts requiring
2- or 3-axis machining. Students will design, model, program, set-up and run
their parts on various machines, including plasma cutters, water jet cutters and
milling machines.
WELD 197 Welding Technology Topics (.5 - 3)

I'm very far off from actually effectively scraping this data but I'm trying to get a start.

My goal is to extract only class name and number and remove descriptions.

Thanks as always!

Comment: Which of the class names are you trying to extract? Every class name or just the first?

Comment: By class name do you mean WELD 190, or WELD 190 as course code, Manufacturing I Introduction to MasterCAM as class name?

Comment: @Enthus3d Correct sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: no worries, I was just clarifying.

Comment: I tried out your code on the example you gave, yielding an output of 

`WELD 190 Manufacturing I Introduction to MasterCAM (3`. Were you looking for how to seperate WELD 190 and the class name, as well as removing the (3?

Comment: @Enthus3d Would love to get rid of the (3. The file is far more complicated and varies wildly in the way its format. Just needed at least a start and figured ')' would be a good one.

Comment: it would be interesting if you could post a pastebin url of it as a link in the question. I might be able to help out a bit.

Comment: You could also make a new question with a REGEX tag to get more people to take a look at it, I'm sure the experts in the house will be able to give you a hand as well :P. As long as you do a bit of work on it and point out some common areas you could potentially parse, your question should be well received.

Comment: @Enthus3d Don't worry about it I should handle it myself. Here is just an idea of what i'm dealing with https://pastebin.com/NDb1JReu

Comment: Ah, I see. If you are going to be parsing a file of that length, this does seem like an undertaking. I suppose you might be able to get away with a REGEX that does _(2+CapitalChars)_(2+Nums)_(Class Name)_(1Num) to grab every course that has that structure, but getting rid of the duplicates and such would probably be a pain. [Here](regexr.com/4le96) is an example I made based on your file. It has trouble dealing with newlines, but the regexr website is what I used a lot with one of my Uni regex-heavy courses. Best of Luck!

Comment: @Enthus3d ingenious, thank you. At least regex is universal I believe.

Comment: oh, no problem at all. It’s easy enough doing it with an online interpreter. And yes, the syntax is fairly universal, although different languages have different levels of support for features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe to solve your current problem, if you're only attempting to parse one line, you will simply need to move your second `line = fp.readline()` line to the end of the while loop. Currently, you are actually starting the parsing from the second line, because you have already used a `readline` in the first line of your example code.

After the change it would look like this:

```
   line = fp.readline() # read in the first line
   fw = open('output.txt', "w+")
   cnt = 1
   while line:
       print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, line.strip()))
       line = line.split(')')[0]
       fw.write(line + "\n")
       cnt += 1
       line = fp.readline() # read in next line after parsing done
```

Output for your example input text:

> WELD 190 Manufacturing I Introduction to MasterCAM (3

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your other class text blocks share the same structure than the one you showed you might want to use a **regular expression** to extract the class name and class number:

Following I assume that every text block contains the information "XX hours lecture" at the same order where 'XX' stands for any kind of number (time frame). In the variable 'match_re' I define a regular matching expression to match only to the defined spot 'XX hours lecture'. And by using 'match.group(2)' I restrict my match to the part within the inmost bracket pair.

The matching expression below probably won't be complete for you yet since I don't know your whole text file.

Below I extract the string: *WELD 190 Manufacturing I Introduction to MasterCAM (3)*

```
import re

string = "WELD 190 Manufacturing I Introduction to MasterCAM (3) 1½ hours lecture - 4½ hours laboratory Note: Cross listed as DT 190/ENGR 190/IT 190 This course will introduce the students to MasterCAM and 2D and basic 3D modeling. Students will receive instructions and drawings of parts requiring 2- or 3-axis machining. Students will design, model, program, set-up and run their parts on various machines, including plasma cutters, water jet cutters and milling machines. WELD 197 Welding Technology Topics (.5 - 3)"

match_re = "(^(.*)\d.* hours lecture)"
match = re.search(match_re,string)
if match:
    print(match.group(2))
else:
    print("No match")
```

Comment: Regex was my second thought i'm just so uncomfortable with it. I was most likely going to implement it at some point because of the more complex structure. Will give this a try. I could post the entire text file it you would like to browse?

Comment: @HYUTS: Sorry for the time delay. I'm not a regex master myself. But yes, if you post the whole text file (or more of the file to comprehend its structure) me or possibly someone else could try some more.

Comment: I don't want anyone to have to spend time on it I appreciate the offer. I just needed a start now that I know I need regex I can try and figure out some type of strategy.